# Not all files are transferring to Github with GitPython

Tags: python, git, github

I'm using the following code on python to push to git (ignore the async and ctx part):

```
    async def gitpush(self, ctx):
        try:
            repo = Repo(os.getcwd())
            repo.git.add(update=True)
            repo.index.commit("Committed")
            origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
            origin.push()
            await ctx.send("Git pushed!")
        except:
            await ctx.send("Some error occured while pushing..")
```

and

```
async def gitpull(self, ctx):
   g = git.cmd.Git(os.getcwd())
   g.pull()
   await ctx.send("Git pulled!")
```

However, if I do so, files that I add / remove somehow don't show up on the repo anymore. Is there any way to add/push all files in the folder to github?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use git from terminal ? or gitbash ?

Comment: Makes it easier for me, as I'm running a bot to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `update=True`, put `A=True`.